# Cannot upload file to Wufoo using their REST API

Tags: php, rest, curl, wufoo

On a website I build we're using Wufoo forms to centralize data. So I have a trivial form that I have to submit to Wufoo, using their rest API.

I did everything according to their documentation, but I still get an error when sending the POST request to their endpoint.

This is how my request looks like:

```
$ref = curl_init('https://{domain}.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/' . WUFOO_FORM_HASH . '/entries.json');
curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_formData);
curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_USERPWD, WUFOO_API_KEY . ':X');
curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ref), true);
```

And this is the $_formData array:

```
Array
(
    [Field4] => firstname
    [Field3] => lastname
    [Field5] => email@test.com
    [Field110] => @/var/tmp/random_name/test.txt
)
```

Whenever I attach a file to the request in Field110, the request fails with this as an error:

```
Array
(
    [Success] => 0
    [ErrorText] => Errors have been <b>highlighted</b> below.
    [FieldErrors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => Field110
                    [ErrorText] => This file was NOT successfully uploaded. Please try again.
                )

        )

)
```

Anyone got this problem before and know any solutions?
I have to mention that I MUST use the Wufoo rest API to submit this.

Comment: [Here is the documentation I was talking about in the question.](http://help.wufoo.com/articles/en_US/SurveyMonkeyArticleType/API-Examples)

Answer (score 1):

The value for `[Field110]` should be a CURL file object.

I found a solution on Github (https://github.com/wufoo/Wufoo-PHP-API-Wrapper/pull/10/commits/094d64436cee405739f5b39bc28f745afed65eb3), which includes the following line:

`$curl_file = curl_file_create($this->value, mime_content_type($this->value), pathinfo($this->value, PATHINFO_BASENAME));`

You might have to replace `$this->value`, just make sure it gets the value `/var/tmp/random_name/test.txt` and pass `$curl_file` to `[Field110]`.

If you want to see another illustration, I've actually implemented this in a WordPress plugin: https://github.com/friendofdog/better_wfi_wordpress/blob/master/front/post-intermediary.php. Look around line 77.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message the file was not properly successfully uploaded. Meaning there is an issue either with the path, size or type of the file.

Max size for a file is 10MB and for all the fields in a single form is 20MB combined.

Why dont you use the [Wufoo API PHP Wrapper](https://github.com/wufoo/Wufoo-PHP-API-Wrapper) it allows among other things to post entries with files....

Comment: **Wufoo API PHP Wrapper** has [known issue](https://github.com/wufoo/Wufoo-PHP-API-Wrapper/issues/9) with file uploading. They have a quite good pull request, but for some reason it is not merged yet.